# How to append data to a variable using \n as separator?

Tags: shell

The new line characters seem to be lost, even though they appear within quotes.

```
foo=
for i in 1 2 3; do
    foo="$foo$(printf '\n')$i"
done

echo "$foo"
123
```

Now in practice, I don't want to add a `\n` before the first element, so I would use a `${foo:+$(printf '\n')}` instead, but first I have to figure out why the code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command substitution removes trailing newlines, so `$(printf '\n')` is the same thing as `$(printf '\n\n\n\n')`, namely the empty string.

To include a newline in a string, put it bewteen single or double quotes.

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
  foo="$foo
$i"
done
```

You may find it less ugly to define a variable to store just a newline.

```
nl='
'
for i in 1 2 3; do
  foo="$foo$nl$i"
done
```

In ksh93, bash, FreeBSD sh, mksh and zsh, but not plain sh (yet), you can also use dollar-single-quote, which allows backslash escapes.

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
  foo="$foo"$'\n'"$i"
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the newline characters was lost, [Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) *ate* them:

> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command
>   in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment) and
>   replacing the command substitution (the text of command plus the
>   enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the
>   command, **removing sequences of one or more < newline > characters at the
>   end of the substitution**

You don't need the `for` loop, just:

```
foo=$(printf '%s\n' 1 2 3)
```

Comment: You also don't need the subshell, you can have `printf` print "into a variable" like `printf -v foo '%s\n' 1 2 3`

Comment: @EricRenouf: `printf -v var` is `bashism`.

Comment: I didn't realize that at first, thanks @cuonglm

Comment: I like your replacement assignment command...that's the first case I've seen where the newline-eating behavior of command substitution comes in *handy*.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard - it almost always does come in handy. Like `cp my_file my_file."$(date)".bak` would be pretty damned annoying if the trailing newline in `date`'s output wound up in the name of `myfile...bak`, you know?

Comment: @mikeserv Where it's annoying  (and a bug IMO) is that it removes more than one trailing newline character.